# Cocoa - Debugging Help

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging

Ok for some reason my code wont play nice and I'm too new to cocoa to figure this out on my own..

when the send button is pressed it is meant to run the createEmail method. But it says
GDB: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". when the button is pressed.

```
#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller
-(IBAction)send:(id)sender{
 [self createEmail];
}

-(void)createEmail{
 NSString *number  = [numfield stringValue]; 
 NSString *carrier = [carrierfield stringValue];
 NSString *carrierTag;

 [carrier lowercaseString]; //make all lowercase 

 //set carrierTag based on what carrier it is
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"verizon"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@vtext.com";
 }
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"at&t"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@txt.att.net";
 }
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"nextel"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@messaging.nextel.com";
 }
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"sprint"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
 }
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"cingular"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@cingularme.com";
 }
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"cingular"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@cingularme.com";
 }
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"virgin"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@vmobl.com";
 }
 if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"t-mobile"]) {
  carrierTag = @"@tmomail.net";
 }

 //Concatenate number and carrierTag to create an email address
 email = [number stringByAppendingString:carrierTag];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see two possibilities. Either `carrier` is not set correctly or it's not equal to any of those strings in which case `carrierTag` is left uninitialised.

In the former case, the exception is probably on the line:

```
[carrier lowercaseString]
```

In the latter, it will probably be at:

```
email = [number stringByAppendingString:carrierTag];
```

The debugger should provide you with that information, and you should provide it to us as well :-)

In addition, [`lowercaseString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lowercaseString) returns another string, it doesn't operate in-place, so you need:

```
carrier = [carrier lowercaseString];
```

What you *may* want to do is set `carrierTag` to an initially empty string so that nothing is appended if there is no match:

```
carrierTag = @"";
if ([carrier isEqualToString:@"verizon"]) {
    carrierTag = @"@vtext.com";
}
:
:
```

Comment: hmm this is intresting...if i type "Verizon" (note the capital V) it returns error. If i type "verizon" nothing happens...

But my program isn't programed to do anything so that means im good? that the capital V is the issue?

Comment: OK, I added [bodyfield setStringValue:email]; to see if if would print out the corect thing and it printed,
number@vtext.com So it works. I'll mark it as solved so no one else posts here. thanks

Comment: @sho: Standard string comparison is case-sensitive and `lowercaseString` returns a new string ... @pax: Sending messages to `nil` doesn't lead to a bad access.

Answer (score 0):

If `carrier` is none of the handled strings, `carrierTag` is left uninitialized - you should at least set it to `nil` and test for that before working with it:

```
NSString *carrierTag = nil;
// ...
if (carrierTag) { 
    // ...
```

There is also the problem that you expect `lowercaseString` to mutate the string - but it just returns a new string that is the lowercase version of the string you called it on. Use e.g. the following instead:

```
carrier = [carrier lowercaseString];
```

Note that you could greatly simplify the lookup of the carrier-tags by using a dictionary, e.g.:

```
NSDictionary *carrierTags = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"@vtext.com", @"verizon",
                               // ...
                               nil];
NSString *carrierTag = [carrierTags objectForKey:carrier ? carrier : @""];
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that although initializing to nil is certainly a good first step, it's also not a good idea to pass nil to most AppKit methods, so calling stringByAppendingString: with a nil argument should be avoided as well.

Comment: @smo: Sure, i didn't mean to imply that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems pointed out in the other answers, `email` appears to be a member variable, and you are assigning it an autoreleased value--meaning it will become garbage as soon as the event loop finishes, and you'll almost certainly crash the next time you access it. You need to retain the value when you assign it.

If you are new to Cocoa, you should absolutely read [Apple's introduction to memory management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).